# Python apache beam remove elements from data set

Tags: python, apache-beam

While I have a data set including keys and several elements (a.k. values?):

```
['7 juni', '215', '196', '219', '228', '200', '234', '212']
['8 juni', '228', '236', '215', '229', '214', '231', '224']
```

I would like to only use the first and last element, but I want to keep them as elements and not strings.
`"| beam.Map(lambda item: item[0] + ' ,' + str(item[7]))"` produce the strings of:

```
7 juni ,212
8 juni ,224
```

I want the elements

```
['7 juni', '212']
['8 juni', '224']
```

Is this possible using python beam transforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want only the last element to be preserved, you could write

```
pcoll = ...
results = pcoll | beam.Map(lambda input: [input[0], input[-1]])
```

which if pcoll is

```
['7 juni', '215', '196', '219', '228', '200', '234', '212']
['8 juni', '228', '236', '215', '229', '214', '231', '224']
...
```

would produce a PCollection of

```
['7 juni', '212']
['8 juni', '224']
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what beam is, but this is a pretty simple problem. Running this (which I think is analogous to your application):

```
groups = [['a',1,2,3],['b',4,5,6,7]]
results = []

for group in groups:
    key = group[0]
    for val in group[1:]:
        results.append([key,val])

print(results)
```

results in this `[['a',1], ['a'.2], ['a',3], ['b',4], ['b',5], ['b',6], ['b',7]]`